# Can I selectively ignore the thesaurus file in a SQL Server full-text query?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, thesaurus

Can I choose to ignore the tsENU.xml thesaurus file in a full-text query in SQL Server 2005?

```
IF @x = 0 THEN
    BEGIN
        SELECT FROM FREETEXTTABLE(use subtitutions and expansions in thesuarus)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT FROM FREETEXTTABLE(just match based on the exact query terms, no thesuaurs)
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the second query's search value(s) in quotes.  Per the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx):

> ```
> FREETEXTTABLE (table , { column_name | (column_list) | * } 
>           , 'freetext_string' 
>      [ ,LANGUAGE language_term ] 
>      [ ,top_n_by_rank ] )
> ```
>
> freetext_string is wordbroken,
>   stemmed, and passed through the
>   thesaurus. If freetext_string is
>   enclosed in double quotation marks, a
>   phrase match is instead performed;
>   stemming and thesaurus are not
>   performed.